# Not seeing notification report for messages that are sent by firebase-admin sdk

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin, firebase-console

I am using firebase-admin SDK to send the message to devices. The device can receive the message. I go to the firebase console to see the report of these messages, but I can not see any information about the message that I just sent. So Am I missing some configuration on firebase or missing some code when I send a message to a device?

Comment: I think the UI only shows the messages sent via the UI. Messages sent from the SDK/APIs do not appear in the console.

Comment: do you know how to get notification reports or statistics if we use firebase-admin SDK?

Comment: Got any solution around this ?